# What CSS could I use for Curved list item effect onhover?

Tags: css

I want to put a 3d curved look in a list item I have whenever you hover on a list item at my sidebar .

How would I do this with css?

EDIT::

I have a list in a side bar.

When I hover over a link I would like it to appear as if it is written on the curved surface of a cylinder

Comment: What exactly is a "3d curved look"? Could you find or draw an example to show us?

Comment: The functional requirement is too vague to give a clear and definitive answer. What exactly do you mean with it? Can you post a screenshot or point a website with similar thing? As far now I can't come up with better suggestions than `background-image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background of the list item to contain a 3D curved image

```
 li:hover{
  background: url(/images/curved3Dbackground.png);
 }
```

Because IE6 only supports this type of Hover on anchor elements, you may want to apply the hover to an anchor inside the list element

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="link.html">Text</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
 li a:hover{
  background: url(/images/curved3Dbackground.png);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

An hover effect you simple do with OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut...

Readm more:

http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/a-simple-mouseover-hover-effect-with-jquery/

So:

- get basic image
- get 3d image
- When mouse get over the item -> OnMouseOver set the 3d Image
- When mouse get out the item -> OnMosueOut set back the basic image

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would need a background image to do this.  All browsers support the hover attribute on an anchor tag (which I doubt you use for your menu container), but some of the newer ones support the :hover attributes for all elements.  I know firefox supports this

```
div:hover{background-image:url(myImage.png);}
```

Then just have the background image your 3d curvy thing.